# Rexx: increment current time value

Tags: rexx

Hi I'm running REXX script on ZOC terminal and i want to display current time and ETA like this:

start time 22:44:24 

end time 22:56:24

but I don't know how to increment current time ???

maybe to convert time to seconds then increment it and then convert time in seconds back to hh:mm:ss ??

I tried this way but dont know how to convert back time from seconds

```
intTime= TIME('S')+900

say="start time " TIME()
say="end time " intTime
```

Comment: I increment the current time by waiting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be along the lines of:-

```
intTime = TIME('S') + 900
hours = (intTime % 3600) // 24
minutes = (intTime // 3600) % 60
seconds = intTime // 60
endtime =  RIGHT(hours,2,'0') || ":" || RIGHT(minutes,2,'0') || ":" || RIGHT(seconds,2,'0')
```

**NOTE!!** I don't have access to test this and it's been many years since I've written Rexx or had access. However, I think the basic process would work. That is:-

1) Extract the **hours** as an integer from the **time** (*catering for the the potential to cross into the next day or days* ie the `// 24` ()).

2) Extract the **minutes**, as an integer, from the **time**, after dropping/subtracting the hours (the remainder of the time divided by hours ie `intTime // 3600`).

3) Extract the **seconds**, as an integer, from the **time**. By obtaining the remaining of diving the time by 60 (will drop hours and minutes).

4) Building the end string as a concatenation of the hours, minutes and seconds. With : as the separator between two values (or surrounding the middle values). The **right** function to include a leading zero.

You could also try:-

```
intTime = TIME('S',TIME('S')+900,'S')
```

That is based upon [TIME](http://nokix.sourceforge.net/help/learn_rexx/funcs7.htm#TIME), which may be Object Rexx. I did also read something mentioning an extended TIME/DATE functionality. However, again that may have been referencing Object Rexx. Although, Mike Colishaw's name was mentioned.

*Mike Colishaw, I believe, being the creator of the Rexx programming language.*